# Hi, I need to pass a base 64 encoded string to javascript function and wants the function to display image in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass a base 64 encoded string to javascript function and wants the function to display image in new tab. I'm generating the html dynamically from java and calling the JS function there.I'm getting syntax error as unexpected token, whenever i try to call that function by clicking that hyperlink.

My java code:

```
String base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(CscmFcnaRes1.getImage()).trim();
```

Dynamic html generated using stringBuffer:

```
                            .append("<A href=\"#\"")
                            .append(" onClick=displayImage(")
                            .append(base64Image)
                            .append(")>"
```

JS function:

```
function displayImage(base64Image) {
    var newTab = window.open();   
    newTab.document.open();   
    var isPdf = base64Image.substring(0, 4) === 'JVBER';
    var mimeType = isPdf ? 'application/pdf' : 'image/jpeg';      
    var htmlContent = '<html><body>';
    htmlContent += '<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="data:' + mimeType + ';base64,' + base64Image + '">';
    htmlContent += '</body></html>';      
    newTab.document.write(htmlContent);
    newTab.document.close();

}
```

I cant change anything in terms of bringing additional frameworks as its a prod running application. I need this image to be displayed in a new tab. When i manually decode the base64 string, I'm able to see the image. Note the base64 string  is around 80k characters.

Comment: Hi JVBER is pdf

Comment: I'm getting that pdf from rest api in a java program, sometimes the api will return pdf's or sometimes images, so i want to handle both the things, so i'm doing like this, I can add the sample encoded string but the comment doesnt allow such a large string